# How to set the height of a cell depending on a UILabel with a typewriter effect

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitableview

I have a UILabel in a cell of UITableView.

To adjust the height of the cell depending the height of the label, it's ok, it works perfectly.

But I need to add another constraints.
I need to display the UILabel with a typewriter effect (letter by letter).

My extension for the effect works well:

```
extension UILabel{

    func setTextWithTypeAnimation(id:String, typedText: String, pauseCharacterArray: [Int:Double], characterInterval: TimeInterval = 0.06 ) {

        text = ""

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

            for (index, character) in typedText.characters.enumerated() {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.text = self.text! + String(character)
                }

                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: characterInterval)
            }

        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I tried to call this function in my configureCell fund :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ParagraphTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ParagraphTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self
    self.configureCell(cell: cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
 }


func configureCell(cell: ParagraphTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let paragraph = paragraphArray[indexPath.row] as! Paragraph

    let pauseCharactersArray:[Int:Double] = [1:0, 6:0]
    cell.dialogueLabel.setTextWithTypeAnimation(id:"intro", typedText: "lorem ipsum", pauseCharacterArray: pauseCharactersArray)
}
```

But the label doesn't appear. I think it's because the height of the label in the cell is set to 0, and it's never updated.

I don't know how to adjust the height of the cell "in live" (every time a character is displayed)

EDIT

I use autolayout

EDIT 2

The typewriter effect, run in a simple UILabel without UITableView:

[image: gif]

The cell set in the xib:

[image: xib]

When I run, the UILabel doesn't appear:

[image: run]

Comment: Can you show some output wireframe what is type writer effect of your label ? and also what is the current error output you have ?

Comment: @BharathVankireddy Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to achieve using a different method.

- I created a stack view to group the label and the buttons (and a sub stack view to line up your buttons).
- On button's stack view, I pinned the height through IB.
- On parent stack view. I pinned the stack view to cell's margin.
- On label, I pinned both sides to fit the stack view (do not pin the bottom side, you are free to pin the top side)

Here is my [IB Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCMR6.png) to use as reference.

- On your ViewController, set the following properties:

  ```
  yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  yourTableView.rowHeight.estimatedRowHeight = 40 // You should set an initial estimated row height here, the number 40 was chosen arbitrarily
  ```
- I edited your method to add an callback.

  ```
  func setTextWithTypeAnimation(id:String, typedText: String, pauseCharacterArray: [Int:Double], characterInterval: TimeInterval = 0.06, callBackAfterCharacterInsertion:(()->())?) {

    text = ""

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

      for (_, character) in typedText.characters.enumerated() {

          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.text = self.text! + String(character)
              callBackAfterCharacterInsertion?()
          }

          Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: characterInterval)
      }

      group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
      //do something
    }
  }
  ```
- And through the callback, I called the `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`, from the TableView, after each character update.

Hope this help you in any way.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution but I don't know if it's a very clean one.

I added layoutIfNeeded() in configureCell method :

```
func configureCell(cell: ParagraphTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let paragraph = paragraphArray[indexPath.row] as! Paragraph

    cell.layoutIfNeeded() 

    let pauseCharactersArray:[Int:Double] = [1:0, 6:0]
    cell.dialogueLabel.setTextWithTypeAnimation(id:"intro", typedText: "lorem ipsum", pauseCharacterArray: pauseCharactersArray)
```

}

And I added the heightForRowAtIndexPath method in my controller, which returns the height of my label:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ParagraphTableViewCell") as! ParagraphTableViewCell

    return cell.dialogueLabel.frame.height
}
```

It works, but I don't understand exactly why, because in heightForRowAtIndexPath I'm returning the height of the label and not the height of the cell.

If someone has a better solution, I'm interested.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are doing it requires a little bit of refactoring: you need a reference to the tableView inside your TypeWriter function. Anyway, a quick and dirty fix is as follows:

First you add a weak reference to tableView in your cell:

```
class ParagraphTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
weak var tableView: UITableView?
[...]
}
```

Then you go seek for it inside your main cycle, to tell the tableView you are updating stuff:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let delegate = (self.superview?.superview as? ParagraphTableViewCell)?.tableView {
                        delegate.beginUpdates()
                        self.text = self.text! + String(character)
                        delegate.endUpdates()
                    }
                }
```

I wouldn't recommend having such approach in an app and you surely want to refactor this into a more solid pattern, my example shows how it works with your code.

I've created a working example to test my code, git it [here](https://github.com/TeamPacMan/TypeWriterCells/)

Comment: Thanks I'm using the code of @VKawai, but it's very similar to yours. I am a little concerned if you said that it's not a solid pattern.

Comment: There are many issues to address: concurrency of typewriting and Single responsability for instance. Ideally you should have a central model, and drive updates from there. Anyway as a first lean step I think this might do.